# Given 2 sides of a triangle find cosine of an angle

Tags: trigonometry

I am studying A level maths on my own as an interest. I have the following problem:

In $\triangle ABC, AB = 9 cm, AC = 12 cm, \angle B = 2\theta, \angle C = \theta.$
Without using tables or calculators find $\cos\theta$ and the length of BC.

Using the cosine rule I have established that:$$\cosθ =  \frac{(x^2 + 63)}{24x}$$ and $$\cos2\theta = \frac{x^2 - 63}{18x}$$ where x = BC.

I can also see that $\angle A = π - 3θ$ and that using the cosine rule $\cos 3\theta = \frac{x^2 - 225}{216}$

That’s as far as I can go.

Comment: At some stage you will probably want to use $\cos(2\theta) = 2 \cos^2(\theta)-1$ or something similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sine rule , $$\frac{\sin {2\theta}}{12}  = \frac {\sin \theta}{9}$$
$$ \frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{12}9$$
$$\cos\theta = \frac 23.$$